# Difference Between Photographs Of And Photographs With?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> 1.Photographs of my teachers and my parents are taken.
>
> 2.Photographs with my teachers and my parents are taken.

Are these sentences different in meaning?

Comment: The first sentence clearly states that teachers and parents feature in the photos. The second could be interpreted as in: *With my teachers and parents, I took photos of the strange bird.* That's to say that you, your teachers and your parents were all taking photos.

Answer (score 1):

> photographs of *something*

means the main subject of the photograph is the *something*

> photographs with *something*

means the *something* is included in the photograph.

Photographs *of* teachers and parent will most certainly be photographs *with* teachers and parents, but a photograph *with* teachers and parents may be of the school building which happens to have teachers and parents in it.